# Getting an address and the cointain in GDB

Tags: gdb

I have a program in ASM (NASM) and I want obtain an address, but some strange error happen when I was debugging with GDB (I typed "next" and the program exited). Is there some bug in GDB?

**test.asm**

```
BITS 32

section .text
global _start

_start:
call function
mov eax,0x41414141



function:
# esi get the address of "mov eax,0x41414141"
pop esi

# Exit
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx
mov al,0x01
int 0x80
```

**Debugging**

```
$ nasm  -f elf test.asm
$ ld test.o -o test
$ gdb -q ./test
Reading symbols from /root/Desktop/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) info functions
All defined functions:

Non-debugging symbols:
0x08048060  _start
0x0804806a  function
(gdb) b function
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804806a
(gdb) run # Execute _start
Starting program: /root/Desktop/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804806a in function ()
(gdb) # We're going to execute "pop esi" now
(gdb) next # Execute only 1 instruction
Single stepping until exit from function function,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 26492) exited normally]
# WHY EXIT? We was going to execute "pop esi" !!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used "next" which tells gdb to do source level step (move to next line in source). As you did not build your executable with debug information included gdb does not know how to do this.
There are two solutions:

1. Build with debug info enabled. I do not know nasm, but it looks it uses the usual -g switch to enable debug info. Add this when assembling.
2. Use nexti in gdb. This will just execute next assembly instruction and will not care about source.